# Higher-order function on async coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Let's say I have a function :

```py
def f(x):
    return {"x": x}
```

I can create a higher-order function that behaves like so :

```py
def augment(func):
    def augmented_function(x):
         return {**func(x), "metadata": "test"}
    return augmented_function
```

And then `augment(f)(1)` will return `{"x": 1, "metadata": "test"}`.

But what if `f` is an async coroutine, this augment function does not work (`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'f' was never awaited` and `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not a mapping`) - I want the augmented function to be a coroutine that can be awaited :

```py
async def f(x):
    return {"x": x}

def augment_async(coro):
   xxx

augment_async(f)(1) # Should return <coroutine object xxx>
await augment_async(f)(1) # Should return {"x": 1, "metadata": "test"}
```

Does anyone know how to write `augment_async` in this case?

Thanks.

EDIT :
Bonus question.

How to write `augment_async` such as `await augment_async(f(1))` returns `{"x": 1, "metadata": "test"}`?

Comment: Just make augmented function `async` and then await `func` inside

Comment: `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable`. Do you have a full code example for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sufficient to make the inner function `async`, so that it can `await` the wrapped function:

```
def augment_async(func):
    async def augmented_function(x):
         return {**await func(x), "metadata": "test"}
    return augmented_function

await augment_async(f)(1) # evaluates to {"x": 1, "metadata": "test"}
```

---

To “augment” an instantiated coroutine `f(1)`, a single layer is sufficient:

```
 async def direct_async(coro):
     return {**await coro, "metadata": "test"}
```

Note that unlike `augment_async`, which produces a factory for coroutines, `direct_async` produces a coroutine directly - its result may be `await`ed only once.